# How to config Swagger with Wildfly Swarm?

Tags: java, swagger, wildfly, wildfly-swarm

I am following https://wildfly-swarm.gitbooks.io/wildfly-swarm-users-guide/content/v/2017.3.3/advanced/swagger.html. But it is not working.

My pom.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
  <artifactId>swagger</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
  <artifactId>swagger-webapp</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

My ApplicationSetting .java

```
  package example.api;
    @ApplicationPath("/example/api")
    public class ApplicationSetting extends Application{

    }
```

I want to crawler all API in example.api.controller.v1 package

```
package example.api.controller.v1;
@ApplicationScoped
@Path("/v1")
public class AuthController {

}
```

My swarm.swagger.config file:

```
packages:example.api.controller.v1
root:api
title:WildFly Swarm Demo
```

But when i run http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html?url=/example/api/swagger.json. It is not working with the result of swagger.json is:

```
{swagger: "2.0", info: {}}
swagger: "2.0"
 info: {}
```

Could anyone help me with this, please!

Thank you so much.

Comment: Have you found a solution?